# unable to parse h1 element following execute_script()

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** the h1 element after the click of a JS link. As I'm new to python, selenium, and beautifulsoup, I'm not sure if what followed the JS execution changes the way parsing works, or if I'm just grabbing the new url improperly. Everything I've tried has returned something different, from Incompleteread, Nonetype object is not callable, [-1, None, -1, None], to a simple None. I'm just not sure where to go after the containers variable, which I left the way it is just to pull the html.

All I'm wanting to pull from this is the name

```
<div class="name"> <h1 itemprop="name"> Nicolette Shea </h1>
```

---

```
star_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='/pornstar/']")

click = driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', star_button)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

try:
    wait.until(EC.url_contains('-'))
except TimeOutException:
    print("Unable to load")

new_url = driver.current_url

page = pUrl(new_url)

p_read = page.read()
page.close()

p_parse = soup(p_read, 'html.parser')

containers = p_parse.find('div', {'class' : 'name'})

print(containers)
```

Comment: what is pUrl  please?

Comment: @QHarr pUrl is urllib.request, urlopen as pUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not after your wait simply load driver.page_source into BeautifulSoup?

```
#try:
#except: ....your code 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
names = [item.text for item in soup.select('div.name')]
```